# Reading & Transforming JSON Object into Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I want to transform a JSON object into an array.

Am using a PHP script to create a JSON file using this code:

```
$stores = array();
$i=0;
$reponse = $bdd->query('select * from store ');
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
    $stores[$i] =  $donnees;
    $i++;
}

var_dump($stores);

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($stores));
fclose($fp);
```

In my JS file am using this code to load the data:

```
var json_obj = $.getJSON("results.json", function (data) {
    json_obj = data;
    return json_obj;
});

 alert(JSON.stringify(json_obj));
```

Now I want to transform my JSON object into a JavaScript array. But in specific way:

```
var props=[] ;

props.push({title:json_obj[0].name,Data:json_obj[0].Description});
props.push({title:json_obj[1].name,Data:json_obj[1].Description});


$.each(props, function (i,v)
{
  console.log(i,v);
});
```

Comment: Arrays in javascript MUST have numeric index, start at 0 and have no gaps.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand you.

Comment: it means: when you say "array[0].title" then the entry at offset 0 will become an object

Comment: i edited my code please have a look at it

Comment: looks good, console.log() it and see what it really got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can simply parse the json into your var props to create the array object...

```
var props = JSON.parse(json_obj);
```

props is now a js array object built from parsing your json string...

EDIT: proposed change to your js file

```
var props = [];
$.getJSON("results.json", function (data) {
    $.each( data, function(index) {
        props.push({title:data[index].name,Data:data[index].Description});
    });
});

alert(props);
```

omit the rest of the code pushing to new array... just log out props...

Comment: when used it it gave me VM2554:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Sorry... Your getJSON function returns a json object via ajax... No need to map or parse... simply push the pieces into your new array per khem's advise... then you can log your array out to the console...

Comment: it says   -- app.js:85 -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to define array and push elements into it,
why don't you try something like this

```
var someArray=[]
someArray.push({title:props[0].name,Data:props[0].Description})
someArray.push({title:props[1].name,Data:props[1].Description})
```

But its not a good idea if you donot know the length of props array

To convert json object into array you should loop through json object and push individual element into some array

```
var someArray = []
for(var key in json_object){
if(json_object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
   var tmpObj={title:json_object[key].name,Data:json_object[key].Description}
   someArray.push(tmpObj)
   console.log(someArray)
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i kinda understood you but how can i alert the content of the new array and see if it worked!

Comment: use console.log(), not alert

Comment: i used $.each(props, function (i,v)
{
  console.log(i,v);
}); but it says  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: sorry but it said  app.js:84 Uncaught ReferenceError: json_object is not defined